# como solucionar este error EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/david/projecto-ecommerce-2021/ecommerce-project/node_modules/.cache'

Tags: reactjs

Al arrancar mi proyecto (npm start) de React.js me sale este error, e intentado borrar el node_modules para volver a instalar npm pero no me permite borrarlo, alguna solución?

```
EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/david/projecto-ecommerce-2021/ecommerce-project/node_modules/.cache'
```

Comment: [Publicación relacionada](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38323880/5843452)

Answer (score 0):

Debe eliminar el `node_modules` y volverlo a correr con `npm i` en la carpeta que lo requiera, en mi caso fue en una carpeta de front

Answer (score -1):

El problema son los permisos de la carpeta node_module, lo solucioné dandole los permisos necesarios:

sudo chmod -R 777 node_modules/